# Number of capital letters

Tags: string-manipulation, natural-language, benchmarking

I am interested in counting a number of uppercase letters in the text. I do it in the following manner.

```
 text = "This place is situated in Agra, Uttar Pradesh, India on State 
 Highway 62 around 70 km from Agra city and around 55 km from Etawah. 
 Its geographical coordinates are 26 52' 12" North, 78
 \[Degree] 35' 51" East. Three rivers, Yamuna, Chambal and Utangan 
 irrigate its land and separate from the states Madhya Pradesh and 
   Rajsthan"

 res = LetterCounts[StringDelete[text, PunctuationCharacter]]
 Total[Boole[UpperCaseQ /@ Keys[res]]]
```

Any suggestion how to speed up this calculation

Comment: I voted to close, but I am only 75% pro-closing. [The  answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176370/34008) of @rhermans shows that this can be done fast with `StringCount`.

Comment: ok, fair enough.

Comment: Please take a look at the @C.E solutions'. This solution is an order of magnitude faster, and what more important in my opinion it is elegant solutions that not use StringCount.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using rhermans' `testtext`, I would propose this:

```
HammingDistance[testtext, ToLowerCase[testtext]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.00025, 185}`

(Update: ) Here is another one:

```
uppercase = Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"];
StringCount[testtext, uppercase] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.00066, 185}`

Using `Length@StringCases` instead of `StringCount` takes about the same amount of time, `0.00068` in my experiment.

Also, Mr. Wizard mentioned using regular expressions, which can be made fast in the same way (which is not surprising because string patterns are internally converted to regular expressions):

```
regex = RegularExpression@First@StringPattern`PatternConvert[uppercase];
StringCount[testtext, regex] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.00067, 185}`

However, on my computer this is only as fast as using the more appropriate regular expression suggested by Mr. Wizard, it is neither better nor worse.

We can compare this to rhermans' approach:

```
RepeatedTiming[StringCount[testtext, _?UpperCaseQ]]
```

> `{0.00336, 185}`

Both the `HammingDistance` approach and the `StringCases` approach are an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Very elegant solution

Comment: Regarding your second method I think it is worth noting that `CharacterRange["A", "Z"]`, equivalent to RE `[A-Z]` is not the same as `UpperCaseQ` as there are many upper case letters according to the latter that do not fall in that basic set of 26.  This is why I used `\p{Lu}` instead.  `ToLowerCase` handles the extended set properly, so your first solution is robust.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That is why I said "the more appropriate regular expression suggested by Mr. Wizard". However, I don't see the speed of this method varying much with a few more characters in the pattern. If you need to add ten or twenty characters to make it robust, then the performance should not necessarily deteriorate that much.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me you are counting the number of different letters that apear as uppercase and not the total number of uppercase characters present. Here I use the *UN Declaration of Human Rights* without [`PunctuationCharacter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PunctuationCharacter.html) as sample text. I use [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) to show the average time in seconds used to compute, together with the result obtained.

**Test data**

```
testtext = StringDelete[
   ExampleData[{"Text", "UNHumanRightsEnglish"}]
   , PunctuationCharacter];
```

**Your approach**

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Total[Boole[UpperCaseQ /@ Keys[LetterCounts[testtext]]]]
 ]
(* {0.0564, 21} *)
```

**What I think you intended**

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Total@KeySelect[LetterCounts[testtext], UpperCaseQ]
 ]
(* {0.059, 185} *)
```

**My approach**

```
RepeatedTiming[
 StringCount[testtext, _?UpperCaseQ]
 ]
(* {0.0032, 185} *)
```

---

@C.E. offers the best answer so far, using [`HammingDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HammingDistance.html). Using a similar approach but with [`EditDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EditDistance.html) it's the slowest of all.

```
BarChart[
 First /@ {
    RepeatedTiming[(* "HammingDistance" @C.E *)
     HammingDistance[testtext, ToLowerCase[testtext]]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[(* "StringCount Alternatives CharacterRange" @C.E *)


     StringCount[testtext, Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"]]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[(* "StringCount RegularExpression" @Mr.Wizard *)
     StringCount[testtext, RegularExpression["\\p{Lu}"]]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[ (* "StringCount UpperCaseQ" @rhermans *)
     StringCount[testtext, _?UpperCaseQ]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[(* "Length@StringCases" *)
     Length@StringCases[testtext, _?UpperCaseQ]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[(* "Total KeySelect LetterCounts" @
     KirilDanilchenko *)
     Total@KeySelect[LetterCounts[testtext], UpperCaseQ]
     ],
    RepeatedTiming[(* "EditDistance" @rhermans *)
     EditDistance[testtext, ToLowerCase[testtext]]
     ]
    } 10^6
 , ChartLabels -> {
   "HammingDistance\n@C.E",
   "StringCount\nAlternatives\nCharacterRange\n@C.E",
   "StringCount\nRegularExpression\n@Mr.Wizard ",
   "StringCount\nUpperCaseQ\n@rhermans",
   "Length@StringCases",
   "Total\nKeySelect\nLetterCounts\n@KirilDanilchenko",
   "EditDistance\n@rhermans"
   }
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , AspectRatio -> 1/2
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , FrameLabel -> {None, "Time \[Mu]s"}
 , BarSpacing -> Large
 , ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ooh, I see I made a mistake. I want to count the total number of uppercase letters :(

Comment: I added a version using `StringCases` that is fast to my answer.

Comment: @C.E. Plot is now updated.

Answer (score 4):

On my system (v10.1 under Windows) [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) is not quite as fast as [`HammingDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HammingDistance.html) but arguably it is more flexible, and much faster than [`UpperCaseQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpperCaseQ.html)

```
text = ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}];

StringCount[text, RegularExpression["\\p{Lu}"]]  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000420, 342}
> ```

cf.

```
StringCount[text, _?UpperCaseQ]                  // RepeatedTiming
HammingDistance[text, ToLowerCase[text]]         // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00573, 342}
> {0.000300, 342}
> ```

Comment: I always like `RegularExpression` in cases like these :) It's in some sense the right tool for the job, even if my re knowledge is rust.

Comment: @b3m2a1 That's the downside for me too; I had to reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294 for this.